# How to convert a custom string representing a timespan into another format?

Tags: powershell, date-formatting, timespan

I'm trying to create a function that converts a string representing a timespan (format: `aMbb.cccS`, where `a`:minutes, `bb`:seconds, `ccc`:milliseconds) to another format (`hh:mm:ss.fff`). Until now, I only get a timespan object.

Example input: `2M37.526S`

Expected output: `00:02:37.526`

My function:

```bsh
function Convert-TimeString ([String]$Time, [String[]]$Format)
{
    $result = New-Object TimeSpan

    $convertible = [TimeSpan]::TryParseExact(
        $Time,
        $Format,
        [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [ref]$result
    )

    if ($convertible) { $result }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `ToString()` on your `$result` according to your needs:

```bsh
function Convert-TimeString ([String]$Time, [String[]]$Format)
{
  $result = New-Object TimeSpan

  $convertible = [TimeSpan]::TryParseExact(
  $Time,
  $Format,
  [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
  [ref]$result)

  if ($convertible) { $result.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss\.fff') }
}

Convert-TimeString -Time '2M37.526S' -Format 'm\Mss\.fff\S'
```

Output:

> ```
> 00:02:37.526
> ```